# How we can provide query param value based on environment value

Tags: karate

I have post request where based resource url I can retrieve its index.I want to have a test case for this for different environments like pro-pro and prod.
How can make it change values based on environment value??

```
Given url 'url'
And params param_value
And request '{}'
When method post
Then status 200
```

In this param value should be like:- for pre-prod env : http://access.pre-prod.com/entity/id1 and
for prod env : http://access.prod.com/entity/id1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution from : https://github.com/intuit/karate#param

```
And param env_url+entity_id
```

In this I declared env specific url in konfig.js